# Different headers for different parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers

I have some parameters on urls. URLs with one parameter should get own special indexation/crawling rules with `X-Robots-Tag`. This is done by:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=NOINDEX_HEADER:1] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "index, follow" env=NOINDEX_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

The **question** is: how could i modify this rule to assign *to all another parameters beside of `id=` with its values* another `Header set X-Robots-Tag` rule?

My idea were to assign another rule by exclusion of the `id`-parameter, like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=id*$` - but i'm not sure, whether its correct.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=id*$
RewriteRule .* - [E=NOINDEX_HEADER:1] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=NOINDEX_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negation like this in `RewriteCond`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NOINDEX_HEADER:1] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=NOINDEX_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And if i want to exclude just some values of `id`, than: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)id=(1|2|3) [NC]`?

Comment: In that case use: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)id=(?:val1|val2|val3)(?:&|$) [NC]`